# Application stays in memory after exit

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, com-interop

I have one application in C# which also serves as service for a web application at server.  The problem is when we close the application (not from Web), it stays and shows up in task manager keeping all memory. We can kill it from task manager but when it is used from web, every time it creates a new process and keep memory allocated.

What should I do at OnExit

```
public void OnExit()
```

so it should removes any instances of processes it created and clears the memory. I am also doing the Interop cleanup in my code with

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
item = null;
GC.Collect();
```

Please provide some suggestions

Comment: Check that the Main thread exits properly, then check for any foreground threads still working. You can attach to the process, pause it and look in the `Threads` window for any user thread that has not exited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below may work with your process name where it says "process name". Not sure how clean or efficient this may be. GC in .NET should grab the process and kill it eventually, one of the advantages of .NET and CIL languages.

```
public void OnExit() {
 try {
    foreach(System.Diagnostics.Process myProc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
          if (myProc.ProcessName == "process name")
            myProc.Kill();
   } catch(Exception ex) {} 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in C# and .NET framework, you're not supposed to manage memory, but let the framework do it for you.  At some point, the garbage collector will kick in and clean it up.  It's not recommended to call it manually.  I know it's hard to switch the mental paradigm if you're coming from a strict C/C++ background.  This question has been answered elsewhere in many other places.

Comment: it kicks in very late, there is a delay of up to 30 seconds after the app is closed. Is there any way to speed this up?